# Can %matplotlib notebook only be bused in Jupyter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pydev, jupyter

I have this and it works in jupyter in browser:

```
%matplotlib notebook

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
```

However, after I copied it to a python file in the PyDev IDE editor, it always complains the first line:

```
 %matplotlib notebook
```

Error message:

```
Encountered "%" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting one of:     <EOF>      <NEWLINE> ...     "(" ...     "{" ...
```

Does this mean the magic method can only be used in jupyter notebook?

Comment: `Can %matplotlib notebook only be bused in Jupyter?` - yes. These are magic commands and are part of ipython/jupyter. They will not work in the regular python shells.

Comment: Yes. After all, outside of the notebook, what exactly would that be telling matplotlib to do?

Comment: @nitind Actually you can use a similar matplotlib backend that does not need jupyter. But the question seems to be about magic, not backends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It's a jupyter notebook command.

Comment: Then how to make it plot the same as in the Jupyter, if I want to run the code in a file?

Comment: @user697911 You might want to add that to your question. As currently written it is not clear whether you are interested in magic commands, matplotlib backends or both.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't use it in a file (as that's not valid Python syntax), but you can use it in the PyDev interactive console: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html if you have IPython properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

The command in question, %matplotlib notebook, can be used to specify how to display graphs in a Jupyter notebook. If you use %matplotlib inline, the graphs will be displayed as a part of the Jupyter notebook. Using the form of the command that you asked about will display the graph in an interactive form within the Jupyter notebook. Or using %matplotlib gtk will open another program to display each individual graph, which is how Python would display the graphs in any other situation. So the command does not have any use or meaning outside of a Jupyter notebook.